# PNG image that support scaling and changing transparency in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, transparency, resizable

I want to show PNG picture on canvas.
Before it I need to resize it and change transparency.

I found that I can load image and change alpha channel with `PhotoImage` like this:

```
image1 = PIL.Image.open('aqua.png')
image1.putalpha(128)
gif1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
```

Also I can load `PhotoImage` and resize it like this:

```
gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'aqua.png')
gif1 = gif1.subsample(5)
```

But I can't perform both this things on same `PhotoImage`

I understand that `PhotoImage` and `ImageTk.PhotoImage` are different classes in my code.

```
>> print (ImageTk.PhotoImage)
<class 'PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage'>
>> print (PhotoImage)
<class 'tkinter.PhotoImage'>
```

I tried to found functionality that I need in both classes but without success.

Maybe I need perform `subsample` and than convert my `tkinter.PhotoImage` to `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` and then perform `putalpha` but it sounds weird.

Please refer me to right direction about png cooking in Python.

Here is all my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200)
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image1 = PIL.Image.open('aqua.png')
image1.putalpha(128)
gif1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)

# gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'aqua.png')
# next line will not work in my case
gif1 = gif1.subsample(5)

canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `resize` method included in the `Image` class. Here is the modified code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200)
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image1 = Image.open('aqua.png')
image1.putalpha(128)
image1 = image1.resize((image1.width//5,image1.height//5))
gif1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)

canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
mainloop()
```